# L9110 output stage

Tags: h-bridge, motor-controller, push-pull

Does L9110 have a push-pull or open-drain output stage?

As I have measured the output voltage decayed slowly from High to Low when light load is attached and inputs inverted. I would expect a sharp falling edge for true push-pull H-bridge.

Datasheet doesn't say anything related:
https://www.elecrow.com/download/datasheet-l9110.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does L9110 have a push-pull or open-drain output stage?

The data sheet description says: -

> L9110 The ASIC device control and drive motor design two-channel
>   **push-pull** power amplifier

It's not very well-written English but I would definitely say the data sheet thinks it has push-pull outputs. The table of output voltages also confirms: -

> VHout Output high 7.50 7.60 7.70 V
>
> VLout Output low  0.35 0.45 0.55 V